# Error at import data to postgresql using copy with delimiter

Tags: postgresql, import, copy

im am importing data to postgresql with this comand

```
COPY codigos_postales 
(CPRO, CMUN, Nombre_Municipio, CP, Municipio_CP, Lugar_CP) 
FROM 'path' WITH DELIMITER E'/t';
```

But i got this error.

```
ERROR: COPY delimiter must be a single-byte character
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to specify a tab as the delimiter, you want `E'\t'` (the escape character is a backslash not a forward slash) or just a literal tab `' '`.

You can see that with:

```
regress=>     SELECT E'\t' AS backslash, E'/t' AS forwardslash;
 backslash | forwardslash 
-----------+--------------
           | /t
(1 row)
```

If the delimiter is actually the string `/t` then you won't be able to use `COPY`, as it only supports single character delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

your delimiter looks like a little bit complex but not a single byte char... Try with '\t'.